# How can I add xmlns namespace to <html> tag in meteor

Tags: facebook-like, meteor, addthis

This is what I'm trying to accomplish (to integrate Facebook send button using addthis)

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

However the html is out of my control. Meteor also forbids adding attributes to `<head>` such as:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Workarounds that serve the same purpose are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to change it through the raw source. But you can use something in your rendered callback to get to it via:

```
Template.hello.rendered = function() {
    $('html').attr("xmlns:fb","http://ogp.me/ns/fb#");
    $("head").attr("prefix", "og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#");
}
```

This uses JQuery to modify the html tag as soon as Meteor renders the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line in your server side code will resolve your first question.

```
WebApp.addHtmlAttributeHook(function (request) { return 'xmlns:fb=http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'; });
```

I have no idea about your second question...

UPDATE:
Certainly you need to return an object in Meteor 1.0.
    WebApp.addHtmlAttributeHook(function (request) { return {'xmlns:fb': 'http://ogp.me/ns/fb#'; });

Comment: i get Error: HTML attribute hook must return null or object

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
WebApp.addHtmlAttributeHook(function (request) { return {"ng-app":"helloWorld"}});
```

(I wish I could put this as a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/16142297/5203563 but I don't have enough points to comment - I'll upvote it)

This also seems to work to get it added on the client side:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  $('html').attr('ng-app', 'helloWorld');
});
```